# Apache rewrite_module

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem trying redirect some user requests to my Apache server pointing to non existing files, using something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^/a/b/c.* /d/e$1 [L]
```

My intention is that, if some user requests file http://whatever.com/a/b/c/something, which doesn't exist, instead of sending the 404 error, rewrite the URL to get it from http://whatever.com/d/e/something, where I can be sure the file do exist.

I know there are a lot of topics on this, but I did very intense research, and my problem is no matter what combination I try, I can't seem to get the rewrite module to work..

Even with something like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [L]
```

That would presumably redirect EVERY petition to index.html , but it does nothing.

It is supposed to be loaded, as apache2ctl -M outputs **rewrite_module** as correctly loaded

Logging errors at debug level, I only see, users requesting non-existent files, and Apache answering '404 File does not exist' errors..

I'm the server admin so I'm not using .hcaccess, I edit directly the httpd.conf file, so there should be no overriding directives issues.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...to redirect user to the index page.

Comment: This is not what I was asking, thanks anyway.
Anyway I figured out what was happening, I guess that this:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f` needs to have the full server's filesystem path to actually check if it's a file and it exists.

So something like: 

`RewriteCond {DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f`

Worked just fine!